# Convert slice of strings into well structured/keyed(?) JSON

Tags: json, go, slice

I have a pretty simple slice of strings, I can happily convert it into JSON, however I need to add keys for the system that will use it.

As an example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    hosts := []string{"hosta","hostb"}
    bodyData, _ := json.Marshal(hosts)
    fmt.Printf(string([]byte((bodyData))))
}
```

This outputs: `["hosta","hostb"]`

Which is to be expected.

However I want: `{"hosts":["hosta","hostb"]}`

What am I missing?

Yes, I could go ahead and create another struct, but surely I can do something in the call to the Marshal?

https://play.golang.org/p/5bQfO1fw7Lc

Comment: You can create a struct value in the call: `bodyData, _ := json.Marshal(struct {Hosts []string `json:"hosts"`}{hosts})`.   A map is the better solution.

Comment: The reverse of this is done [here](https://jhall.io/posts/go-json-tricks-array-as-structs/). You can probably use this as inspiration, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a map:

```
bodyData, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{"hosts":hosts})
```